# Why Use JS Promises Instead of IF/ELSE / Ternary?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm doing some reading up on JS Promises to up-skill.

Here's my quandry:
Say you want to `console.log('we done, bruh!')` *AFTER* your data's come back.

so with a Promise, you might say:

```
let iWantToLogOut = function() {

    let data = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        resolve(data)
    })
}
```

And then *resolve* that promise like:

```
iWantToLogOut().then((dataBack) 
=> databack.json())
 .then((json) => {
   console.log('We done, bruh! Look: ', json)         
 })
```

So that's great. You get your API data back and *then* we log our msg out.

But isn't it just way easier to go:

```
   let data = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
   data ? console.log('we done, bruh!') : null;
```

I'm probably over-simplifying/missing something (*because... well... i'm retarded*) but I just want to make sure i'm really understanding Promises first before i move onto Async/Await.

Comment: Of course it's easier with if block! The only problem is that it won't work :( Too bad, right? You also set up `iWantToLogOut` wrong. It should just be `let iWantToLogOut = function() { return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users') }`

Comment: If you do this then each time you will hit the else part.

Comment: @DenisTsoi: Timing has nothing to do with it. And the above would always show `we done, bruh!` as the promise returned by `fetch` is a truthy value.

Comment: I'm assuming fetch is not a promise @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @DenisTsoi: `fetch` isn't a promise, it's a function that returns a promise: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: Yes the code is misleading. `Fetch()` returns a promise. It shouldn't just be stored in `let data`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But isn't it just way easier to go:
>
> ```
> let data = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
> data ? console.log('we done, bruh!') : null;
> ```

It would be, but it doesn't work. What `fetch` returns is a *promise*, not the result of the operation. You can't *return* the result of an asynchronous process. More: [*How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

In the upcoming ES2017 spec, though, we have syntactic sugar around promise consumption which will let you write this:

```
let data = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
// --------^^^^^
console.log('we done, bruh!');
```

Note we don't even need the conditional, because `await` converts a promise rejection into an exception.

That code would need to be in an `async` function, e.g.:

```
(async function() {
    let data = await fetch(/*...*/);
    // use data here
})();
```

The JavaScript engines in some browsers already support `async`/`await`, but to use it in the wild, you'll want to transpile with Babel or similar.

---

Note: You've shown

> so with a Promise, you might say:
>
> ```
> let iWantToLogOut = function() {
>
>     let data = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
>
>     return new Promise((resolve) => {
>         resolve(data)
>     })
> }
> ```

There are a couple of problems with that code:

1. It never settles the promise you created if the `fetch` fails.
2. It calls something `data` which is not data, it's a *promise* of data (that's mostly style, but it's misleading).
3. It exhibits the **promise creation anti-pattern**. You already have a promise (from `fetch`), no need to create another.

`iWantToLogOut` should be simply:

```
let iWantToLogOut = function() {
    return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
};
```

That returns a promise that will be resolved with the data, or of course rejected. Which you'd then consume with promise methods or `await` (within an `async` function).

Comment: Interesting re the await vs rejection handling. Will read up on that.
Re the _fetch returning a promise_ stuff. Yes, i had to fight the urge to bolt the `.then()` onto it as i'm so used to doing so. 

I guess that makes sense then. And will look fwd to ES7/Babel'ing these to keep it simpler. @TJCrowder

Answer (score -1):

It is not a matter of easy.
Usually network calls should be handle asynchronously(I don't want to the anti-pattern of synchronous AJAX calls). At that point you have few options to handle it:

1. Callbacks
2. Promises
3. Observables

In you code above, when it's synchronous, the `fetch` should return immediately with a promise that will be resolve to the data only when the server has responded. Only then you can check the data for it's content. Further. Because every promise can be fulfilled or failed, in your then you can have a handler for each instead of using the ternary.

From the latest spec:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest outside of workers is in the process of being removed from the web platform as it has detrimental effects to the end user’s experience. (This is a long process that takes many years.) Developers must not pass false for the async argument when current global object is a Window object. User agents are strongly encouraged to warn about such usage in developer tools and may experiment with throwing an InvalidAccessError exception when it occurs.